# Arreglo para tomar varias columnas para que hagan lo mismo, y no repetir el código

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una hoja en la que quiero que la persona, cuando use una casilla de verificación, ejemplo marque "sí" muestre la fecha y si desmarca sea "no" y muestre pendiente.

```javascript
function myFunction() {
    var sps = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A9eTvHwn14UoBs9Rpr50Zg6tkNmB6jCuM6xV8sHfa5U");
    var sheet = sps.getSheets();
    var data = sheet[0].getDataRange().getValues();


    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var precio = row[1];
        var cantidad = row[4];
        var almacen = row[6];
        culminado = row[8];
        var disponible = (almacen - cantidad);
        var impuesto = (precio * 0.18);
        var totalFinal = (precio + impuesto) * cantidad;
        var nodisponible = ("Pendiente");
        var startRow = 1 + +i;
        sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 3).setValue(impuesto);
        sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 4).setValue(precio + impuesto);
        sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 6).setValue(totalFinal);
        // sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 8).setValue(disponible);


        if (culminado == "SI") {
            sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 8).setValue(new Date());
        }
        if (culminado == "NO") {
            sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 8).setValue(nodisponible);
        }



        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }

    // operador de igualdad

}
```

y de hecho lo que tengo es que si mi columna 9 es igual a "sí" me muestra la fecha en la columna 8 y si es "no" me muestra pendiente. Ahora yo quiero saber cómo puedo replicar esto mismo en otras columnas, o sea que si en la columna 9 marcan "sí" muestre la fecha en la 10, y si marcan "no" muestre pendiente.  ¿Cómo podría realizar este arreglo para tomar varias columnas para que hagan lo mismo, y no repetir el código? por ejemplo:

```javascript
culminado =row[9] ;
sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 10).setValue(new Date());
```

para cada columna donde quiera aplicar mi ciclo, o si existe una manera mejor de realizar este proceso también es bien recibido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una alternativa es usar POO , puedes crea una clase {} con un método que ejecute tu algoritmo , luego creas una nueva instancia para cada columna que desees que tenga esa función

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo de ese metodo andres

Comment: es tu linea de codigo row[9] ; sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 10).setValue(new Date()); donde estas aplicando tus columnas ? row(9) y getRange(startRow , 10) ?

Comment: creo que no entendiste la pregunta andres te explico un poco actualmente tengo dos problemas con mi codigo. uno lo puedes ver en la imagen que subi en la pregunta que impuesto  que es  var = precio * 0.18 me  comienza desde la primera fila y nose como indicar que mi ciclo for recorra desde la segunda.  y si vez la columna opcion cuando escribes si te sale la fecha actual en estado pero si escribes no te dice pendiente yo quiero crear un areglo que me permita usar esta opcion  en otras columnas de la hoja.

Comment: Detalle no menor: `if` no es un ciclo ;)

Comment: tienes un for en el codigo que cumple un ciclo amigo realmente si no va aportar nada util. no comentes sin animo de ofender pero necesito alguien que comprenda el codigo y aporte cosas positivas.  no me voy a poner a explicar un ciclo for un condicional if que son variables como declararlas. para que te sientas mas cómodo.  ya que en ningún lado de la pregunta veo que pidiera explicación sobre lo mismo. ahora si tu vienes y restructuras mi codigo y me explicar de una manera adecuada como realizar la tarea que deseo yo me quito el sombrero y te digo si gracias por el aporte.

Comment: ¡Listo! Por cierto, lee el [código de conducta](/conduct) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de tantas formas

1. Antes del for declara una variable que incluya las los números de columnas, por ejemplo

   ```
   var columnas = [8,10];
   ```
2. Dentro del for reemplaza

   ```
   if (culminado == "SI") {
       sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 8).setValue(new Date());
   }
   if (culminado == "NO") {
       sheet[0].getRange(startRow, 8).setValue(nodisponible);
   }
   ```

   por

   ```
   columnas.forEach(columna => {
     const value = culminado == "SI"
     ? new Date()
     : nodisponible;
     sheet[0].getRange(startRow, columna).setValue(value);

   });
   ```

Lo anterior hace uso de

- Array
- Array.prototype.forEach
- [Operador condicional / Operator ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: gracias ruben excelente aporte realmente lo que buscaba.